# PHP Dynamic table with checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a dynamic table with checkbox. The problem with my code now is that it only should insert the first data in year,code and age. Male and Female would be checkbox, but these two field seem unable to get the correct data, The checkbox should store 1 with it's check 0 if it's uncheck. Please let me know if you see the causes these error in my code, Thank You

POST PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $h = $_POST['h'];

    if($h >= 0){
        for($i=0; $i<=$h; $i++){
            $year=intval($_GET['year']);
            $code=intval($_GET['code']);
            $age = $_POST['age'][$i];
            $male = $_POST['male'][$i];
            $female = $_POST['female'][$i];

            $sql = "delete from remark_details WHERE year=:year";
            $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $query -> bindParam(':year',$year, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query -> execute();


            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO remark_details (year,code,age,male,female) VALUES('year','code','$age','$male','$female')";
            $query2 = $dbh -> prepare($sql2);
            $query2->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php   
    foreach($results as $result){?>
       <tr data-row='0'>
          <td colspan="2"><input class="tableBody" type="text" name="age[]" value="<?php echo $result->age; ?>" autocomplete="off" /></td>
          <td colspan="2"><input class="tableBody" type="checkbox" name="male[]" value="1" autocomplete="off" /></td>
          <td colspan="2"><input class="tableBody" type="checkbox" name="female[]" value="1" autocomplete="off"/></td>
          <td>
          <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove' style='cursor:pointer'>
          <i class='material-icons' title='Delete item'>remove_circle_outline</i>
          </a>
          </td>
      </tr>
<?php }} ?>
<input name='h' type='text' id='h' value=0 readonly hidden />
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('click', function(to) {
        var rows={};

const getparent=(e,tag)=>{
  let n=e.target;
  while( n.tagName.toUpperCase()!=tag.toUpperCase() ){
    if( n.nodeName==='BODY' )return false;
    n=n.parentNode;
  }
  return n;
};


const datedifference=(d1,d2)=>{
  return {
    y:Math.abs( d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear() ),
    m:Math.abs( d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth() +1 ),
    d:( Math.abs( ( d2 - d1 ) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) )
  }
};


document.getElementById('tbl_history').addEventListener('change',function(e){
  if( e.target!=e.currentTarget && e.target.nodeType==1 && e.target.tagName=='INPUT' && e.target.type=='month' ){

    let parent=getparent(e,'tr');

    let duration=parent.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="duration[]"]');

    let row=parent.dataset.row;


    if( !rows.hasOwnProperty( row ) )rows[ row ]={};
    rows[ row ][ e.target.name ]=e.target.value;


    if( Object.keys( rows[ row ] ).length==2 ){
      let keys=Object.keys( rows[ row ] );
      let d1=new Date( rows[ row ][ keys[0] ] );
      let d2=new Date( rows[ row ][ keys[1] ] );

      let obj=datedifference(d1,d2);
      duration.value=[obj.y+' Years' , obj.m+' Months' ].join(' ');
    }
  }
});
document.getElementById('tbl_history').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if( e.target!=e.currentTarget && e.target.nodeType==1 && e.target.tagName=='I' ){
    let p=getparent(e,'tr');
      p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
  }
});

    });

var h=0;
function history() {
  h++;
  var html = `
  <tr data-row='${h}'>
    <td colspan="2"><input class="tableBody" type="text" name="age[]" autocomplete="off" required /></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input class="tableBody" type="checkbox" name="male[]" value="1" autocomplete="off" /></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input class="tableBody" type="checkbox" name="female[]" value="1" autocomplete="off"/></td>
    <td>
      <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove' style='cursor:pointer'>
        <i class='material-icons' title='Delete item'>remove_circle_outline</i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>`;

  document.getElementById('tbl_history').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',html);
  document.getElementById('h').value=h;
}


</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is happening currently? Why are you only parameterizing one of the queries? Is there an element named `add`? Also why have `male` and `female` as columns, just have a `gender` column....none of those are likely to address your current issue, just observations until more info is added

Comment: Because what Im doing here will be allowing user to select both ```male``` and ```female```

Comment: Could have `both`, or `3` and have a `genders` table that maps labels to ids

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this method would suit my case

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you should make yourself familiar with the `checked` attribute of the `input[type=checkbox]` element. See here: [input checked](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

So I use a function like this:

```
function checked(bool $value): string
{
    return $value ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
}
```

And your code should look like this:

```
<input class="tableBody" type="checkbox" name="male[]" value="1" <?php echo checked($result->male) ?> />
<input class="tableBody" type="checkbox" name="female[]" value="1" <?php echo checked($result->female) ?> />
```

You can delete the `autocomplete="off"` attribute in checkboxes. It's not supported in checkboxes, so it is ignored by the browser anyway.

I also recommend to just use one DB field for gender.

If you really want to hide the "h" element, then instead of your code you could use the `type="hidden"` version:

```
<input name='h' type='hidden' id='h' value=0 />
```

**Edit:**

Ok, you told me in the comments that you still have issues when inserting data to the DB. And really, there are a lot of wierd things going on in your code.

First of all, (if it would work) you would in fact insert just one record with your loop, which would be the last one. The year doesn't change in your loop, because of:

```
$year = intval($_GET['year']);
```

maybe this one should be (?):

```
$year = intval($_GET['year'][$i]);
```

Then you try to delete the record for that year (or all records for that year, but I assume there should only be one, which you want to update). But you bind the `WHERE` condition with `PDO::PARAM_STR`. Is the "year" field really a string? You should use `PDO::PARAM_INT` instead or drop the whole `bindParam` line and just use:

```
$query->execute(['year' => $year]);
```

Next, if you are using MySQL you could drop the whole `DELETE` action and use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`. But this can only work, if your `PRIMARY KEY` is "year". The syntax is quite the same as in `INSERT`. Just replace the word `INSERT` with `REPLACE` in your query. The difference is, `REPLACE` deletes the existing record with the same `PRIMARY KEY` before it inserts the new one. `INSERT` would just do nothing or throw an error instead.

Last, your `INSERT` statement is also quite buggy. You do not parameterize your query like the `DELETE` statement, so you could throw away the `prepare/execute` stuff (which I urge you NOT TO DO!) and use just the `query` method. But this would put a wide open door for hacker attacks.

Next, you put in hard the strings `'year'` and `'code'` instead of the variables `$year` and `$code`. And you force the variables `$age`, `$male` and `$female` to be strings by putting them into single quotation marks. But the age sould be an integer, and I assume male and female as booleans.

I recommend using a parameterized statement and execute it with an array of parameters:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO remark_details (year,code,age,male,female) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
$query2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
$query2->execute([$year, $code, $age, $male, $female]);
```

In standard cases this works fine. PDO will sort out the appropriate datatypes for you.

And as final advice: Never trust any user input. You should do some validation/salvation stuff to your `$_POST` parameters. You will always hear this because it's really important.

Comment: Seem liks I could not do ```<?php echo checked($result->male) ?>```, because after including this code, my whole page was stucked to load

Comment: Do you have inserted the function, too? Maybe before then whole `foreach($results as $result)`?
You also could do: `<?php echo $result->male ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ?>`.

Comment: Yes, I've added in the function in javascript

Comment: I've also tried to add in the ```<?php echo $result->male ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ?>```, but its still the same

Comment: The function I wrote is a PHP function, not a JavaScript function.
Do you get some error message? Do you have a proper error handling? For useful error handling in PHP see [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).

Comment: So the function should be place inside the foreach ？

Comment: No, outside. You just have to declare it once.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but seem that there's still problem inserting the data into the db

Comment: Just added some more help to my answer... :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think the main problem righ now is that the value of my checkbox is unable to be inserted to the DB, I've tried remove the checkbox type and my dynamic data can be insert to the DB smoothly. But with the checkbox, my insert query seems to be not responsive or will be inserted with wrong data.